# Filtering the specific data for response in DRF

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework, response

I have following response data

```
[
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Default Group",
    "permissions": [
        22,
        24
    ]
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Another Group",
    "permissions": [
        1,
        2,
        22,
        24
    ]
},
{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "New Group",
    "permissions": [
        10,
        11,
        12,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8
    ]
}]
```

**But I want to remove the dictionary whose id = 10 from the response data ,how can I do that ?**

I have following lines of code..

```
class GetUserGroupList(APIView):


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    groups = Group.objects.all()
    serializer = GroupSerializer(groups, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**In serializers.py**

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'permissions',)
```

**Any help would be appreciated !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you do something as following :

```
groups = Group.objects.exclude(id=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include/exclude certain items from the response, you can filter queryset for achieving that. I recommend you to use generic API views like below:

```
from rest_framework import generics


class UserGroupListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    queryset = Group.objects.exclude(permissions=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the seializers.py stuff you mentioned but I wrote this one-liner than gets the job done:

`response = [i for i in response if i['id'] != 10]`

Basically, it iterates through the list `response`, creating a new list that is also called `response`, except the new list does not contain any dict with an `id` of 10

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had earlier solution as below but ,there are other better ways in answers as well

```
 groups = Group.objects.all()
    serializer = GroupSerializer(groups, many=True)

    data_is = list(serializer.data)
    print(type(data_is))
    for item in data_is[:]:
        if item['id'] == 10:
            data_is.remove(item)
    print(data_is)

    return Response(data_is)
```